# ExtJS store sync send empty string instead of null

Tags: extjs, extjs-stores

I have a `store` with `model`, and this `model` have `fields` like below:

```
{
    name: "name",
    type: "string",
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: null
}
```

**Problem is:** When I update `textfield` with name on empty string, I send "" instead of `null`

`textfield` have `allowNull: true`

How to send `null`?

Answer (score 1):

> {name: "name", type: "string", allowNull: false, defaultValue: null}

I think `allowNull` should be `true`

Comment: sorry my mistake - but if i set allowNull on true in model not working same